# stat_contour with data labels on lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wonder how to get data labels on lines in `ggplot2` for contours. Thanks

```
require(grDevices) # for colours

x <- seq(-4*pi, 4*pi, len = 27)
y <- seq(-4*pi, 4*pi, len = 27)
r <- sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+"))

rx <- range(x <- 10*1:nrow(volcano))
ry <- range(y <- 10*1:ncol(volcano))
ry <- ry + c(-1, 1) * (diff(rx) - diff(ry))/2

plot(
    x = 0
  , y = 0
  , type = "n"
  , xlim = rx
  , ylim = ry
  , xlab = ""
  , ylab = ""
  )

contour(
    x = x
  , y = y
  , z = volcano
  , add = TRUE
  )

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
volcano3d <- melt(volcano)
names(volcano3d) <- c("x", "y", "z")

# Basic plot
v <- ggplot(volcano3d, aes(x, y, z = z))
v + stat_contour()
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

using directlabels package and picking solution from [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/C2Gy-wk8HM8)

```
# Basic plot
v <- ggplot(volcano3d, aes(x, y, z = z))
library(directlabels)
v2 <- v + stat_contour(aes(colour = ..level..))
direct.label(v2, method="bottom.pieces")
```

[image]

Comment: with ggplot > 2.0.0 you'll need to add `method="bottom.pieces"` (or `top.pieces`) to the `direct.label` call

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question already answered, but I do a lot of contour plots and I think that there is an easier and more versatile way to do this using the package metR (https://rdrr.io/github/eliocamp/metR/f/vignettes/Visualization-tools.Rmd). This package has the function geom_label_contour() that provides an easy way to plot labels of contours. Also provides a lot of functions to plot maps.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(metR)
volcano3d <- melt(volcano)
colnames(volcano3d) <- c('x','y','z')

ggplot(data = volcano3d, aes(x=x,y=y,z=z)) + geom_contour() +
  geom_label_contour()
```