# Error: No Default label placement from this type of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, direct-labels

Why am I getting this error?   Here is the R script and the data set I am trying to plot salinity contours for ([link to data here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3wo5m63k3m2jso/ASsalinity.csv?dl=0)):
It looks like this (first 10 rows):

```
    Longitude   Latitude    Salinity
1   -76.7027969 35.8915787  0.094745182
2   -76.67744141    35.8915787  0.10131969
3   -76.65208591    35.8915787  0.109281363
4   -76.62673042    35.8915787  0.118873653
5   -76.60137493    35.8915787  0.130326379
6   -76.57601943    35.8915787  0.143826847
7   -76.55066394    35.8915787  0.159496078
8   -76.52530845    35.8915787  0.177391073
9   -76.49995296    35.8915787  0.197562864
10  -76.47459746    35.8915787  0.220200511

ASsalinity <- read.csv("~/ASsalinity.csv")
library("ggplot2")
library("directlabels")
plot1<-ggplot(ASsalinity)+geom_raster(aes(Longitude,Latitude,fill = Salinity),data=ASsalinity)+geom_contour(aes(Longitude,Latitude,z=Salinity),data=ASsalinity)
plot1
```

I can get the contours plotted on the ggmap, 
[A plot of the salinity contours in Albemarle Sound, NC.  Longitude (x) and Latitude (y), and an interpolation program was used to generate the salinity at all other points on a grid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFoNI.png)

but the direct.label command is throwing this error:

```
direct.label (plot2)
```

If the defaults are used:

```
Error in (function (geom, p, L, colvar, ...)  : 
  No default label placement for this type of ggplot
```

If I specify a position placement:

```
direct.label (plot2, "bottom.pieces")
```

I get a different error:

```
'ggproto' is not an exported object from 'namespace:ggplot2'
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to put labels on?

Comment: I can't reproduce this plot with the given data, but you probably need something like `aes(colour=Salinity)` in `geom_point` (if you want to label the points)

Comment: I want to label the contour lines with the salinity.

Comment: Hmm, I think it's because you didn't map colors to the contours.  See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627735/stat-contour-with-data-labels-on-lines).  It works for me if I use `direct.label(v2, "bottom.pieces")` as you do.

Comment: I tried this: `> plot1<-ggplot(ASsalinity)+geom_raster(aes(Longitude,Latitude,fill = Salinity),data=ASsalinity)+geom_contour(aes(Longitude,Latitude,z=Salinity,colours=..level..),data=ASsalinity)
> direct.label(plot1,"bottom.pieces")`
Now I get a different error: `Error in split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...): 
  group length is 0 but data length > 0`

Comment: I tried the volcano v2 example suggested by aosmith above and it works, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Maybe `stat_contour()` is different than `geom_contour()`?

Comment: I think I must use `stat_contour`.   This worked: `> plot1<-ggplot(ASsalinity)
> plot2<-plot1+stat_contour(aes(Longitude,Latitude,z=Salinity,colour=..level..),data=ASsalinity)
> direct.label(plot2,"bottom.pieces")`

Comment: Also, I updated to ggplot2 2.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered the answer to my own question, with the help of aosmith. The key was upgrading to ggplot2 2.1.0 and then using `stat_contour()`. Below, I updated my code, while adding a base map with ggmap 2.6.1:

```
library("ggmap")
library("ggplot2")
library("directlabels")
 ASmap3<-get_map(location= c(lon= -76.16,lat=36.08),zoom=9)
plot1<-ggmap(ASmap3)+stat_contour(aes(Longitude,Latitude,z=Salinity,colour=..level..),data=ASsalinity)
 direct.label(plot1,"bottom.pieces")
```

Here is the map: 
[A map of Albemarle Sound, NC, USA with labeled salinity contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbQ4S.png)